# VBA Remove Duplicates Error

Tags: vba, excel

So, I am trying to delete any rows that have duplicate data in column A. I thought this was pretty elegant compared to some of the loops I saw people asking about. However, I get an error on the line rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes. The error is Run-time error 1004. Application defined or object defined error.

Ideally, we can get the error to go away while also removing duplicates rows. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
Private Sub RemoveDuplicate_Click()

  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Worksheets("Scorecard")

  LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set rng = ws.Range("A1:K" & LastRow)
  rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Also, I tried this code as well and got the same error.

```
Private Sub RemoveDuplicate_Click()

 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim rng As Range
 Worksheets("Scorecard").Activate
 LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K" & LastRow)
 rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1),  Header:=xlYes
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-removeduplicates-method-excel

> Columns: Array of indexes of the columns that contain the duplicate
>   information.

Comment: I replaced my line of code with the one you said and still got the same error. I tried it with both of my examples above.The error is Run-time error 1004. Application defined or object defined error. Also occurring at the same spot.

Comment: What's the value of `LastRow` when it fails?

Comment: Your code works fine for me (even without the Array() edit)

Comment: I added a msgbox to print LastRow. It returns 138

Comment: There was a blank row. A2 was a blank row. I changed the code from set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K" & LastRow) to set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:K" & LastRow) and it worked. Thanks Tim!